# What's wrong with my midnight time?

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm using powershell to get a usage report of a Microsoft Azure environment.
To define the start and end times I use the following:

```
$reportedStartTime = (Get-Date -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)
$reportedEndTime = (Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)
IF($reportedEndTime -eq $reportedStartTime)
    {
    $reportedStartTime = ($reportedStartTime).AddMonths(-1)
    }
```

Then I run:

```
Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime $reportedStartTime -ReportedEndTime $reportedEndTime
```

But I get the following error:

```
Get-UsageAggregates :  
InvalidInput: The reportedstarttime for daily aggregation granularity 
must have the time set to midnight (0:00:00Z).
```

However, if I call the variable `$reportedStartTime` and just copy paste the output:

`Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime "01 September 2016 00:00:00" -ReportedEndTime "01 October 2016 00:00:00"`

It works...
What is going on here?

Comment: Someone screwed up and didn't set the server's timezone to UTC.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually this is ran from my workstation, because our firewalls block all access to Azure except for from a few workstations. And my workstation is set on RST. So, indeed that is my problem. In passing my datetime object the remote server running UTC thinks I'm passing 23:00... And the solution below (changing my get-date into a string by parsing it as a datetime string) works. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You forgot `-Millisecond 0`, so your `DateTime` is some milliseconds past midnight.

Comment: @PetSerAl Nope, I tried that and it did not resolve the issue. It also doesn't seem to store milliseconds unless I define them manually.

Comment: It in fact store milliseconds: `(Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).TimeOfDay`, it just not display milliseconds part by default. Does it work, if you put it this way: `[DateTime]::SpecifyKind((Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0 -Millisecond 0), 'Unspecified')`?

Comment: @PetSerAl Didn't have time to try it before, but I now tested with milliseconds specifically defined as 0 and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I think we can use this script to get the usage report:

```
$reportedStartTime = (Get-Date -day 1 -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).datetime
$reportedEndTime = (Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).datetime
IF($reportedEndTime -eq $reportedStartTime)
    {
    $reportedStartTime = ($reportedStartTime).AddMonths(-1)
    }
Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime $reportedStartTime -ReportedEndTime $reportedEndTime
```

Here is my result:
[The usage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8iWy.png)
If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Comment: This works, adding the datetime parses the object as a string, meaning the remote server doesn't try to translate it to local time and I get the correct results back!

Answer (score 0):

Internally the .net DateTime type has a "Kind" property that is set to the time zone you are in when creating the DateTime. You need this "Kind" to be UTC.

In .net I do like this DateTime.UtcNow.Date to get UTC today.

(Yes I know the question is powershell - I am just explaining why I think it fails - then a powershell savvy person can say how to accomplish this in powershell )